# Random loop with code to prevent duplicate output returns no output at all from time to time

Tags: wp-query, loop

I have a custom taxonomy with several quotes assigned to each term. Two terms (`general` and `yoga`) share the same pool of three quotes. On my `front-page.php` i randomly draw one quote from each term and display it as an introduction to each section. In the case of the terms `general` and `yoga` i've included a failsafe, the variable `$do_not_duplicate`, to prevent that in the second draw the same quote is picked again and that i have the same quote twice on a single page. The code of the first block is:

```
    <blockquote class="container" style="color:#287da2;">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'quotes',
            'thesections' => 'general',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'orderby' => 'rand'
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
        <q><?php the_field( 'quote_text' ); ?></q><br><cite><?php the_field( 'quote_origin' ); ?></cite>
        <?php endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();
            else: ?>
            <p>DB error</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </blockquote>
```

The code of the second block is:

```
    <blockquote class="container" style="color:#1f8665;">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'quotes',
            'thesections' => 'yoga',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'orderby' => 'rand'
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>
        <q><?php the_field( 'quote_text' ); ?></q><br><cite><?php the_field( 'quote_origin' ); ?></cite>
        <?php endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();
            else: ?>
            <p>DB error</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </blockquote>
```

Problem is, it works most of the time, but after two or three page reloads, where the quotes are updated properly and no duplicates are shown, it happens that the second block remains blank with no output while the first block shows a quote. No php errors in the logs are shown, nor errors in wp debug mode - nothing. Is it due to the small number of quotes in the term (3 quotes) or is there an error in the code? I literally have no idea what the problem is in this case and what leads to those no shows in the second block every few reloads. :/ Best regards Ralf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is *how* you're doing the exclusion. It's happening *after* you've grabbed your second quote. If it matches the first quote, it just silently fails to appear.

Try this for your 2nd block:

```
<blockquote class="container" style="color:#1f8665;">
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'quotes',
        'thesections' => 'yoga',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post__not_in' => array( $do_not_duplicate ),
        'orderby' => 'rand'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <q><?php the_field( 'quote_text' ); ?></q><br><cite><?php the_field( 'quote_origin' ); ?></cite>
    <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        else: ?>
        <p>DB error</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</blockquote>
```

The `post__not_in` parameter will prevent `WP_Query` from selecting your `$do_not_duplicate` post in the first place.

### Reference

- [`WP_Query` Post & Page parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)

Comment: Thanks for explanation and clarification as well the suggestion to solve the issue. Works perfectly! Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help.